# How to get file upload value in front-end to put in ACF image field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to upload image and the image should be inserted in a new post but I can't get the image displayed in the post editor even if the image is successfully uploaded. 
Here's my upload button:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

This is the code I added in my php action form:

```
$target = "/www/opt/wp-content/uploads/user-uploads/";
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {      
  $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];     
  $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];    
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$target/$name");     
}

update_field($field_5559871286b9b, $_FILES, $new_id);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First, verify that the file has been uploaded successfully. The [`wp_handle_upload`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) function is great for simple processing of the upload itself.

Once it's uploaded, in order to attach the file to the ACF field, you'll need to [process it as a WordPress attachment](http://www.jqui.net/wordpress/acf-upload-image-made-easy/) so that the Media Library and ACF are aware of it.

Finally, after the attachment is created, you can use the **attachment ID** (along with the ACF **field key** and your **post ID**) to update the ACF field so that it references the new media item:

```
update_field('field_12345', $attachment_id, $post_id);
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to update a ACF file input when submitting the file from frontend

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it works fine for me

```
/*
 * Function to upload feature image for post on front end form
 */
function insert_attachment( $file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false' ) {
    if ( $_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {
        return __return_false(); 
    }

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

    //set post thumbnail if setthumb is 1
    if ( $setthumb == 1 ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id );
    }

    return $attach_id;
}
```

The you would use this in button 
`<input type="file" name="file" id="file">`

Answer (score 0):

Where image is the name of your ACF field.

```
$image = the_field( 'image' );
printf( '<img src="%s" />', $image );
```

or try

```
$image = get_field( 'image' );
```

Comment: It isn't correct, because he wants update field 'image' from Frontend